# Do flutter compile its code to ARM binaries?

Tags: flutter

I read somewhere that Flutter compiles its code to ARM binaries. These ARM binaries can be understood by both ios and android and thats how flutter achieves cross-platform. If so where can we see ARM binaries? Are APK and ARM binary the same?
Can someone share some more details on it?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-mobile-apps-makers-are-in-love-with-flutter/#:~:text=How%20Does%20Flutter%20Work%3F,software%20for%20a%20specific%20platform.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation about the comparison of dart's compiled binaries and android's apk. The page also has explanation about iOS platform compilation with Flutter. This paragraph also talks about how the Flutter VM is used, just in case you wanted to know about the JIT compiler. https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#run-android

> The engine’s C and C++ code are compiled with Android’s NDK. The Dart
> code (both the SDK’s and yours) are ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled into
> native, ARM, and x86 libraries. Those libraries are included in a
> “runner” Android project, and the whole thing is built into an .apk.
> When launched, the app loads the Flutter library. Any rendering,
> input, or event handling, and so on, is delegated to the compiled
> Flutter and app code. This is similar to the way many game engines
> work.
>
> During debug mode, Flutter uses a virtual machine (VM) to run its code
> in order to enable stateful hot reload, a feature that lets you make
> changes to your running code without recompilation. You’ll see a
> “debug” banner in the top right-hand corner of your app when running
> in this mode, to remind you that performance is not characteristic of
> the finished release app.